# Multiple local require_one vs. Single global require_once?

Tags: php, processing-efficiency, require-once, memory-efficient, coding-efficiency

I'm working on a project where Ajax is used a lot, and my PHP code is Object Oriented. (@SomePeople, I know static is not OOP -_-)
Let's say I have 2 classes, each in a file :

```
/* class1.php */
class Class1 {
    public static function Method1(){ return 'blabla1'; }
    public static function Method2(){ return 'blabla2'; }
}

/* class2.php */
/* require_once Here ? */
class Class2 {
    public static function Method1(){ return 'LoL'; }
    public static function Method2() {
        $var = Class2::Method3();
        /* or require_once Here ... */
        $var .= Class1::Method1();
        return $var;
    }
    private static function Method3() {
        /* ... and Here ? */
        return Class1::Method2();
    }
}
```

Not that ridiculous of course, It's just an example.
So, I'm gonna call Class1 methods in Some (not all) methods of Class2, And each Ajax call is going to call only 1 method from Class2 So ...

```
/*Ajax call 1*/
echo Class2::Method1();

/*Ajax call 2*/
echo Class2::Method2();
```

Therefore, in some calls, I don't need to include "class1.php" file.
It's not only these methods But a lot more.

**Now my question is** which one is more efficient?

1. To call 'require_once' at the top of 'class2.php' like files, so that 'class1.php' is included globally. **Downside : ** 'Class1' may never be used in the process.
2. To call 'require_once' at the top each function in 'Class2' like files, so that 'class1.php' is included locally. **Downside : ** 'require_once' may be called multiple times.

Which one are the standard and a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: *"Which one are the standard and a more efficient way to do this?"* -- use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). It will load only the needed files, when classes they declare are used. If the names of your classes follow the [PSR-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) standard, [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) is able to generate an autoloader for you.

Comment: *"my PHP code is Object Oriented." -- `static` methods and properties are not OOP; they are just global functions and variables with fancy names.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion. Well, I just took a look to see what it. It seems that I can't use 'autoload' because I'm including these classes in different directories, And their Directory address is no way included in class names.  
About OOP, I know you got what I meant.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you use the classes. It's important only that the class name matches the file name that contains it (only one class per file) and the class namespace matches the directory path where the file is located. The class `A\B\C` must stay in the file `A/B/C.php`. Or you can write your own autoloader that implements your own rules.